# Wave equation even solution

Tags: wave-equation

$u_{tt} -c^2u_{xx}=F(x,t) $  , $ x>0$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$  , $ x\ge 0$

$u_t(0,t)=g(x) $ ,  $ x\ge0$

$u_x(0,t)=0 $ , $ t\ge0$

I did an even expansion to solve it for $-\infty<x<\infty$
I get that the solution for my problem is even with the variable $x$.

**Now my question is why **$u_x(0,t)=0$** is true given that the solution $u(x,t)$ is even with x ?**

Comment: What do you mean by $u_t(0,t) = g(x)$? The left side is independent of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u(x,t)$ is even and differentiable in $x$ we have:
$$ u_x(0,t) = \lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{u(h,t)-u(0,t)}{h} = -\lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{u(-h,t)-u(0,t)}{-h} =$$
$$ - \lim_{h \uparrow 0} \frac{u(h,t)-u(0,t)}{h} = - u_x(0,t)$$
So $u_x(0,t) = -u_x(0,t)$, thus $u_x(0,t) = 0$.